# do postback after enter hit on changing text in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I make postback after user changes textbox text and hits enter ?
Is only javascript real solution. Doesnt asp.net give any out from box solution for such a problem ?
Thank You for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the javascript solutions, you can place the `textbox` with a submit `button` inside a `panel` and make use of `DefaultButton` property of the panel.

Below is the code example: -

Your aspx will look like this

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Now, when you press enter inside the text box the button click event occurs, same as by clicking the button.